# Db schema migrations in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am wondering what is the correct way to arrange a db schema migration script/scripts.

My current script is a c# code made out of {version}.cs files which I am running one by one in an incremental way.

1. Is it recommended to put your schema migrations script in a C# code or should I always keep it as pure `sql` file?
2. When using `Alter table` I need to add a condition and check whether the `Alter` had been done already before. So if creating a `SQL` script I should add something like `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME='table' AND column_name='col')`. looks like a lot of code, Is this the way to go?
3. One of the guys suggested using a `Stored-procedure` and write the schema migration script inside it to leverage on the advantages of a `Stored-procedure`, What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Db schema migration from what to what?

Comment: There are _many_ different schema changes, and a _many_ corresponding ways to undo them.  Add/drop column/table/database/index.  Change size (up or down) of integer/varchar/etc.  Split/merge database/table/column.  Change default/charset/collation.  How much to you want to take on?

Comment: I have all of the above, Very big script which updates on every version, I am just wondering of the common way of arranging your migration script. Via pure .sql files ? Via C# file for instance?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is obviously no rule, but it's probably a good idea to be consistent. It's also a question of whether these schema changes will be executed by someone perhaps less skilled in running SQL scripts, e.g. if the database and its application is a product you're distributing to others.
2. While MariaDB supports statements like `ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS col_name;` (see [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-table/)) , MySQL doesn't have this. You could create a stored procedure to do this, perhaps something like [this](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mysql/howto_add_column_unless_exists.htm).
3. Stored procedures are great for a number of tasks, but this sounds like more work than it's worth. I won't reject the idea completely, as it all depends on your specific use-cases. When migrating big tables you may instead want to use a tool like [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) in Percona Toolkit.